# Pusher keeps giving 401 error on production

Tags: pusher

I have Pusher integrated into my web app.  It's a Java based app running on Windows server 2008.  The Pusher Server library is the one available on their website.

I've been using Pusher on my development machine and staging machine with no problem.  I only use public channels, and only 2 public channels (an admin channel and an "other user" channel.  Everything works as expected when my application is deployed to dev or staging servers.

Errors start occurring when I push to production though.  I continually get 401 errors, like Pusher isn't authenticating my credentials.  This is despite the fact that the credentials between dev/staging/prod are exactly the same, and the code is unchanged.

Am I missing some setting?  Firewall setting?  Is Pusher caching some information I don't know about?  I'm at a loss about where the problem could lie.

To prove the error is specifically on the production server only, I can log in as an "other user" against the production machine (loading the Pusher client code), then fire an event as an admin on my development machine (loading the Pusher server code) and it works.  When I fire the same admin event from my production machine, that's when the 401 errors occur.

```
Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://api.pusherapp.com/apps/....
```

Answer (score 2):

Found this after digging around a while.  My system time was off by an hour on the production server, which gave the error from Pusher, and explains why it worked fine on dev and staging but failed on production with exactly the same code.

Comment: THANK YOU! Spent half a day debugging this only to find that my VM was off by 30 minutes - d'oh!

Comment: I am new to pusher with Laravel. But I was getting "Error 401" on pusher. After reading your answer. I change my windows time to automatically set and its working fine now.